# How do I add a event to an ASP.NET control when the page loads?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

ASP.Net web forms, .NET 2.0

I have a dilemma.  I have an aspx page that has a custom control:

```
<def:CustomControl ID="customID" runat="server" />
```

The custom control can be added multiple times to the ASPX page if certain criteria is met:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="options" OnItemDataBound="options_OnItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
                <td>
                    <span>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="optionName">
                        </asp:Label>
                        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="optionValues" CssClass="PartOption" >
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </span>
                </td>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

In the code behind of the aspx page, I wanted to append a event (OnSelectedItemChange) to the dropdown control that isn't actually on the ASPX page (yet).  However, when I try to do something like the following in the code behind:

```
foreach(Control eachControl in customID.Controls) {
    if (eachControl.HasControls) {
        Control DdControl = eachControl.FindControl("optionValues");  //always null

        if (DdControl != null && DdControl is typeOf(DropDownList)) {
            DdControl = DdControl as DropDownlist;  //I might have the syntax wrong
                                                    //here, but you get the point.

             //add event to control.
        }
    }
}
```

But All that eachControl has is a repeater, and it shows its childcontrol count as 0.  So when it get to the FindControl method, it always returns null.

**QUESTION**
So what I am trying to do is add an event (OnSelectedItemChange) to the dropdownlist control inside the repeater (which is a custom control that gets added to the page if criteria is met).  When a selection is made in the drop down, I want it to trigger the Event method.

How can I either:

A) Find a way to add the event if the dropdownlist control exists on the page?

OR

B) A way to be able to call a method in the code behind and pass the selections from all the drop down lists (since the custom control could be added more than once creating multiple drop downs?

**NOTE** I don't have the code in front of me, so if I have something syntactically incorrect, please overlook.  I also know that ID's are unique, so this is also assumed to be a problem with my logic. When it renders these, the ID's might be mangled by the asp name convention which I would assume I have to find a way around.

Comment: First of all in which method do you try to execute the above code?
Secondly why not create an event on the custom control. This might very well not be the only time someone's going to want to subsribe to the selectionchanged event

Comment: Do you mean `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the DropDownList?

Comment: @LordCover - yes.                                                       @Rune FS  - I am not sure I follow.  I updated the above custom control.  But since the code for the custom control is on a separate page, how putting it on the "<def:CustomControl> control on the ASPX page affect the dropdownlist control embedded in the Repeater of the custom control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create that event on the custom control, you won't need to check if it exists on the page or not. If it does, it will definately trigger the event. Or am I missing something here?

---

**EDIT:**

What you'll have to do is declare a public event on your control, then when the SelectedIndexChanged Event fired, you'd fire that event, and receive it on the page.

So on your control you'd have:

```
public delegate void MyIndexChangedDelegate(string value);
public event MyIndexChangedDelegate MyEvent;

protected void myDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyEvent(myDropDown.SelectedValue); // Or whatever you want to work with.
}
```

Then on your page, on your control declaration you'd have:

```
<usc:control1 runat="server" OnMyEvent="EventReceiver" />
```

And on  the code behind:

```
protected void EventReceiver(string value)
{
    // Do what you have to do with the selected value, which is our local variable 'value'
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "Alert", string.Format("<script language='JavaScript'>alert('User selected value {0} on my DropDown!');</script>"), value);
}
```

That should work.

Comment: The ASPX page that the <def:CustomControl> is a separate page/class from the custom control logic class.  So I can't put the event (OnSelectedIndexChanged) on the dropdownlist control that points to a method on the code-behind of the ASPX page (it won't know about it and won't build). Thats the essence of the problem.

Comment: @pghtech I see. So I've edited my answer and added some code. Hope it works for you.

Comment: This doesn't work.  And I don't see how I am binding anythign to the dropdownlist to be able to apply any logic.

Comment: @pghtech What do  you mean you don't see how to bind your DropDown? What's important that you get from your DropDown? The SelectedValue, the SelectedText? I've changed code sample to capture the selected value and expose it to the page, so that you can work with it inside Page's context.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you can't put this logic in the control itself, what you need to do I think is access that repeater and attach an ItemDataBound event to it. Something like this:

```
Repeater options = customID.FindControl("options") as Repeater;
if (options != null)
{
    options.ItemDataBound += new RepeaterItemEventHandler(OptionsItemDataBound);
}
```

Then in the ItemDataBound event you would do something like this:

```
void OptionsItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
     DropDownList optionValues = e.Item.FindControl("optionValues") as DropDownList;
     if (optionValues != null)
     {
         //perform logic you need here
     }
}
```

I don't have time to try that out right this minute, but I suspect that should work.

Comment: But what makes the event I am bind the repeater to fire (OptionsItemDataBound)?

Comment: Also, I found I can find the repeater, but it doesn't have any controls - ??

Comment: The repeater I am assuming to already have a data source associated with it. This is just adding in an extra hook so you can perform additional work if need be. As far as the repeater controls, you won't find any. You'll need to access the DropDownList from the ItemDataBound event in order to perform additional steps related to those controls.